# How do I find a pattern in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, algorithm, pattern-matching

So picture you having a string like this

```
o7o7o7o7o7o
```

There is a clear pattern of `o7o`
my approach was to find the second `o` after the first one and that would be the pattern, and then see if it matches through out.

the string is, how do I get the index of the second `o` ?

I tried this

```
var pattern = "o7o7o7o7o7o";
var index = input.IndexOf("*");
```

But that is obviously going to get the first index of the first `o` it finds, I want to get the second one.
How do I do that?

Comment: you want to get index of `o` after `7` from your above string?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: You didn't specify `input` and `pattern.IndexOf("*")` will give you `-1`. I find the question unclear, do you want to find a pattern or test for one?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this many ways, the fastest way would be **a loop**:

```
string pattern = "o7o7o7o7o7o";
int count = 0;
int index = 0;
while(index < pattern.Length)
{
     if(pattern[index] == 'o') count++;
     if(count == 2) break;
     index++;
}
```

and `index` is what you want.

**Linq:**

```
int index = pattern.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
              .Where(a => a.x == 'o').Skip(1)
              .FirstOrDefault().i;
```

**string.IndexOf():**

```
int count = 0, index = 0;
do
{
    index = pattern.IndexOf('o', index);
    if (index != -1) { count++; index++; }
} while (index != -1 && count < 2);
```

and there are lots of other ways, but I think the three above examples would be fine as other ways I think of are slower (at leat those I can think of).

Comment: What if you had a string that looked like this `"o7o7oo7o7o7o"` that would make it uneven, is there a way to identify that?

Comment: if you mean get the index of second `o` yes all these there examples work, no matter how the pattern is, if this is not what you meant, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Also could use Regex like so:

```
var pattern = "o7o7o7o7o7o";

var regex = new Regex("7(o)");

var matches = regex.Matches(pattern);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Index);
}
```

Comment: i think `7(o)` gives the desired output that OP want instead of `o7(o)`

Comment: He said "find the second o after the first one" which this will do, as well as each in the series. Unless I'm not understanding the question correctly.

Comment: yes he want to get index of `o` after 7. read comments in question.

Comment: Ahh didn't notice that, you are correct. Changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Build  prefix function and look for compressed representation as [described here](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/prefix-function.html)

> Given a string s of length n. We want to find the shortest
>   "compressed" representation of the string, i.e. we want to find a
>   string t of smallest length such that s can be represented as a
>   concatenation of one or more copies of t.
>
> It is clear, that we only need to find the length of t. Knowing the
>   length, the answer to the problem will be the prefix of s with this
>   length.
>
> Let us compute the prefix function for s. Using the last value of it
>   we define the value k=n−π[n−1]. We will show, that if k divides n,
>   then k will be the answer, otherwise there doesn't exists an effective
>   compression and the answer is n.

But your string is not representable as (u)^w because it has excessive char at the end. In this case check divisibility of `(i+1)` 
 (i is index) by `(i-p[i])`

For  `s = '1231231231'` we can get representation `(123)^3+1` because the last `(i+1)` divisible by `k[i]=3` is 9

```
  i+1: p[i] k[i]
  1 : 0  1 
  2 : 0  2 
  3 : 0  3 
  4 : 1  3 
  5 : 2  3 
  6 : 3  3 
  7 : 4  3 
  8 : 5  3 
  9 : 6  3 
  10 : 7  3
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of the second occurrence of `o` when there should be at least 1 time not an `o` in between you might use a regex using a capturing group and get the index of that group:

`^[^o]*o[^o]+(o)`

That would match:

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `[^o]*` Match 0+ times not an `o` using a negated character class
- `o` Match o literally
- `[^o]+` Match 1+ times not an `o` using a negated character class (use `[^o]*` if there can also be 2 consecutive o's).
- `(o)` Capture `o` in a group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xe6lit/1)

```
string pattern = @"^[^o]*o[^o]+(o)";
string input = @"o7o7o7o7o7o";

Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Index); // 2
```

[Demo c#](https://rextester.com/LZHKA93713)